# Error constructing as per schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following defined in my server.js,

```
//server.js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    "userName": {
        type: String,
        unique: true
      },
    "password": String,
    "loginHistory": [{ 
        "userAgent": String,
        "dateTime": Date
    }]    
  });
  var User;

  module.exports.initialize = () => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let db = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds237409.mlab.com:37409/web322_a6");
        db.on('error', (err)=>{
            reject(err); // reject the promise with the provided error
    });
    db.once('open', () => {
        User = db.model("users", userSchema);
            resolve();
    });
    })
};
```

I have a function that is called when posting to my `app.post('/register')` route, and it basically builds a new User, then assigns it to the passed data, and resolves it afterwards.

```
module.exports.registerUser = (userData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (userData.password != userData.password2) {
            reject("Passwords do not match!");
        }
        let newUser = new User(userData);//<!-- 'Error: TypeError: User is not a constructor'
        newUser.save((err) => {
        if(err.code == 11000) {
            reject("Username already taken");
        } else {
            reject("Error creating User: " + err);
        }
        // exit the program after saving
        //process.exit();
        resolve();
        });
    })
}
```

At first I thought I've misdefined User, but I seem to have initialized it properly, as per the MongoDB documentation. Any thoughts? It keeps throwing `Error: TypeError: User is not a constructor`

EDIT: /post / register

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    console.log("entering1");
    dataServiceAuth.registerUser(req.body).then((data) => {
        res.render('register', {successMessage: "User Created"});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
        res.render('register', {errorMessage: err, userName: req.body.userName});
    })
});
```

Comment: Where are you requiring and calling `initialize()`? Also, you're not exporting your User model, if you want `initialize` to return the model you should add it to `resolve` and get its value from the `then` call. Idk, this seems like a weird way to structure your project.

Answer (score 0):

My error was in,

`let db = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds237409.mlab.com:37409/web322_a6");`

The greater than and less than signs are not to be used. Proper string:

`let db = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@ds237409.mlab.com:37409/web322_a6");`